# Can't remove the Android ActionBar

Tags: android

I've try to change my manifest, using `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` and also change `onCreate()` method but my app always crashes.

this is my manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

and my MainActivity():

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Please paste crash logs.

Comment: Did your problem was solved?

Answer (score 2):

Your `MainActivity` class extends from `AppCompatActivity`. So is required that  `MainActivity` theme must be **Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)**

So make your theme `AppTheme.NoActionBar` extends from `Theme.AppCompat` like this:

```
 <style  name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      ...
 </style>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

In styles use this code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

  </style>
```

And use this theme name in AndroidManifest.xml in Application tag:

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```